# Instagram style android layout?

Tags: android, css, android-layout, instagram

I am pretty new to android layout, I want my `CardView layout` look like:

[image: Instagram Style]

With view count, user name and icon on top and image in the middle, and description in the bottom.

I searched and couldn't find one place to start, can anyone give me a hint or place of samples?

I am thinking maybe I need a linearly layout of part a, part b and part c

part a: a Relativelayout for top icon, view counts and username

part b: a image view

part c: description.

Is it a right track to implement it?

Comment: Seems OK to me. Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet, I am still learning relativelayout stuff, it will be great if there is a sample I can follow

Comment: Requesting samples is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try a Custom Listview, these are some nice tutorials: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already implemented recycleview, now I only need to decorate my cardView.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.